# Anchor links are not working in android

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox, anchor

Web links are not clickable in android chrome and firefox. But in Opera it is working. It is created with Twitter bootstrap :

http://questionfriends.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in computer if you resize the browser to minimum width the links doesnt seem to work. It has something to do with the scalfolding javascrip[image]t that is making the links as simple "#" .

While if you maximize it on desktop the link seems working. Some scalfolding code is removing the hyperlinks with dummylinks. Just check if any javascript is doing it,

Comment: Yes the "Go to top" div covers the whole window in responsive mode